# How to read this lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Can someone read me the following line lambda.

```
n => n % 2 == 1
```

Also if I have to write the same piece of code without lambda how would I write it. It might make me understand.

Another piece of code is below

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>{11,37,52};
List<int> oddNumbers = numbers.where(n => n % 2 == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: Don't know what language but looks like a lambda that takes n and returns true if it's not divisible by 2

Comment: this should be a simple modulo operation, which returns odd numbers

Comment: @aaronman check the tags on the question. This is c#. Check out your visual scanning son.

Comment: @Gusdor you should prolly check when the questions tags were changed and then realize that I got the question right anyway

Comment: For future reference - I copied the code above, pasted to LINQPad utility and found it would not run because numbers.where should have a uppercase W like numbers.Where

Answer (score 4):

Reading the expression out loud would be

```
n 'goes to' n modulus two equals one
n     =>    n    %     2    ==    1
```

Essentially, you can think of this lambda as a function that returns true when the value provided to it (`n`) is odd and positive, false otherwise. You could also write this as a method

```
bool IsOddAndPositive(int n)
{
    return n % 2 == 1;
}
```

Using it as in your snippet would be

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>{11, 37, 52};
List<int> oddNumbers = numbers.Where(IsOddAndPositive).ToList();
```

And the result (of both what you've specified and the method example) is

```
11, 37
```

Answer (score 1):

this function

```
  n => n % 2 == 1
```

takes one argument (n) and return boolean value:

- true, if n is odd: n % 2 == 1 (n is odd if and only if it has remainder 1 when divided by 2)
- false otherwise (if n is even)

When re-written as ordinary function it would be equivalent to

```
  Boolean IsOdd(int n) { -- <- I've named it "IsOdd" since lambda functions have no explict names while ordinary functions have
    return n % 2 == 1;
  }
```

Your code below

```
  List<int> oddNumbers = numbers.where(n => n % 2 == 1).ToList();
```

i's a LINQ expression which selects odd values from the list

Comment: To nitpick: it returns true, if `n` is odd *and positive*.

Answer (score 0):

As for youer problem, how you would write it without lambda:

```
int[] digits =  {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int[] OddDigits = new int[5];

for(int i = 0; i < digits.Length; i++)
{
  if(digits[i] % 2 == 1)
  {
       int x = 0;
   OddDigits[x] = digits[i];
       x++;
  }
}
```

I just replaced the list with arrays for simplicity. As I stated in my comment earlier, it is a simple modulo operation

Answer (score 0):

Line 1 instantiates a list of 3 integers
The % operator, also called modulo operator, computes the remainder after dividing its first operand by its second

The results of the second line will be a list containing 11 and 37.

you could write this like this using a foreach:

```
        List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 11, 37, 52 };
        List<int> oddNumbers = new List<int>();
        foreach (var num in numbers)
        {
            if (num % 2 == 1)
            {
                oddNumbers.Add(num);
            }
        }
```

you could also use Array.ForEach, like this:

```
        numbers.ForEach(num =>
        {
            if (num % 2 == 1)
                oddNumbers.Add(num);
        });
```